# Extract fixed values from json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object as :

```
[
 [
    "A",
    "1"
 ],
 [
    "B",
    "2"
 ],
 [
    "C",
    "3"
 ],
 [
    "D",
    "4"
 ],
 [
    "E",
    "5"
 ],
 [
    "F",
    "6"
 ]
]
```

I want to retrieve all the key/value pair except A, D . Is there any way to do that in javascript ?

Comment: Is it possible to modify your JSON? I may be wrong but it doesn't look valid. It'd be better to be [ { key: "A", value: "1"}, { key: "B", value: "2"}...]

Comment: decoding `json` will give you `array`, than you can remove `A & D` through loop.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a JSON object, but more like a 2-dimensional array.

Here is how you can retrieve a 2-dimensional array excluding the `"A"` and `"D"` elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = [
        [
            "A",
            "1"
        ],
        [
            "B",
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "C",
            "3"
        ],
        [
            "D",
            "4"
        ],
        [
            "E",
            "5"
        ],
        [
            "F",
            "6"
        ]
    ];
    var b = [];
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (a[i][0] != "A" && a[i][0] != "D")
            b.push(a[i]);
</script>
```